# How to implement copy constructor and assignment operator in a templatic container class?

Tags: c++

I have no idea how to cast an int to a double in a copy constructor or either in a assignment constructor. 
Is it possible? How to do it?

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
    Container() { //... }
    Container(const Container& y) { //... }
    Container& operator=(const Container& y) { //... }
    ~Container() { //... }
private:
    // ...
};

int main() {
    Container<int> ci;
    Container<double> cd;
    ci = cd;
}
```

> ```
> no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Container<double>' and 'Container<int>')
>
> candidate: Container<T>& Container<T>::operator=(const Container<T>&) [with T = double]
> ```

Comment: What is `cid`? Did you mean, `ci = cd;`?

Comment: The error message also says that the assignment is `cd = ci`.

Comment: Those would not be copy constructors/assignment operators. Those would be *conversions*. "Copying" in C++, with regard to special member functions, is always from the same type as the destination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your `Container` template all instances of plain `Container` inside the class definition is equal to `Container<T>`. So for a template argument of `int` then all `Container` is equal to `Container<int>`. And that means your `operator=` overload only takes a `Container<int>` argument. The assignment operator declaration you have is equal to

```
Container<T>& operator=(const Container<T>& y);
```

Which for an `int` template argument would be

```
Container<int>& operator=(const Container<int>& y);
```

---

If you want to be able to accept other types as arguments, you need to make the overloaded operators templates themselves:

```
template<typename U>
Container& operator=(const Container<U>& y);
//                                  ^^^
//  Note use of new template argument here
```